# Snippet insertion corrupts content

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

**To reproduce**

Replace indented code with snippet in a question which has more explanation after the code

**Expected result**

Snippet replaces code

**Actual result** (in latest Chrome at least)

Snippet replaces code AND some of the text after the code - unless 3 empty lines before the text

**Example** (***NITPICKERS***: Yes it is not supposed to be in a snippet  but shows the issue)

1. Original question
   [image]
2. Highlighting and cutting code
   [image]
3. After inserting snippet
   [image]

Comment: Picking nits here, but that code shouldn't be in a snippet.

Comment: Clearly the editor behavior is a bug, but why are you trying to turn that into a snippet in the first place?  It isn't a complete runnable example.

Comment: @nitpickers - I used it as an example. I often use the snippet editor to format code or JSON and then remove the top line so it is no longer a snippet. As I commented, the example is poor but it shows the issue which is an issue for ANY code between texts

Comment: I'm having a hard time duplicating this. Playing around with adding a snippet by selecting existing code first isn't obliterating the text just below it. I've tried in the answer box here and in one on Main.

Comment: @BSMP: I can repro this (on Chromium 58 / Linux), but only if I click the snippet button immediately after cutting the code from the edit box. Moving the cursor or making any changes to the edit box before launching the snippet editor makes this bug stop happening. So does even just clicking inside the box. Weird.

Comment: Maybe it's the specific version? I'm on version 57 on my work machine.

Comment: Note that highlighting the code (without removing it) then creating a snippet and inserting it works as expected. I can only reproduce this when taking the extra step of removing the code prior to inserting a snippet.

Comment: Sure I know how to work around, but forget it and then have to redo everything

Comment: I've also experienced this using Chrome 58 on a Win10 machine.

Comment: Oh thank God someone reported this. I thought that it was just me.

Comment: latest chrome has also other issues for me that half of the webs rich text editors don't function properly anymore. they must have changed something big under the hood.

Comment: Reminds me of another site I use that decided to "upgrade" their forum software and now you can't make posts from a mobile device. At least, not without *severe* effort (the software deletes the first space (and first symbol!) after every word, regardless of if the user taps the spacebar or if its autoinserted). I reported it and the site said, "It wasn't meant to be mobile friendly. [Closed: Won't Fix]" The site offers mobile-specific content.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this. Going to do some investigation and see if we can get a fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue should be fixed now. This was an interesting one.

Basically what was happening was that when a user selected text then deleted it, the JavaScript plugin that we're using to detect the cursor selection's end point never updated. That means if you selected something like 50 characters then hit backspace, the editor would still remove the 50 characters after you add a snippet **even though the original 50 characters you selected are now gone**. It basically still thought you were highlighting some text after you hit backspace.

This was actually a problem for *any* of the editor's tools that added text to the body of the editor. This fix should make things a whole lot less confusing now.

Comment: This just happened to me. I was editing my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464112/javascript-looping-an-object-with-typeerror-property-undefined/44464149?noredirect=1#comment75925071_44464149. When I changed the code in the answer to a snippet, the explanation I had after the code disappeared.